# Xcode 7 only generates .m file, no .h file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

My Xcode version is 7.3.1.

I want to create an Objective-C class file with `.h` & `.m` files.

I choose iOS source & Objective-C File like below:

[image]

Then, I want to select "Objective-C class" in file type, but it isn't there:

[image]

So, I select "Empty file" as the file type. But it only creates a `.m` file, there isn't a corresponding `.h` file.

Do I have to create header file & implementation files separately, manually? I remember I used to just create the Objective-C class file, then both header & implementation file were generated for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to for `Cocoa Touch Class` for ex.

[image]

and you get the sub type of

[image]

Comment: No, I don't want cocoa touch class, I need pure Objective-C class with header & implementation files.

Comment: @Leem.fin - just Un check the `also create XIB file` , it will only generate .h and .m file